# Read from inputstream unknown data length

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

I have a system that is sending at random times some data to a tcp port.

The data sent is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Event> usefull XML data </EVENT>
```

I'm using Java, generally I use:

```
BufferedReader inFromClient =
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

        while(true){
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            if(clientSentence == null){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
            //parse XML file
        }
```

But the `<Event>` part does not end with `"\n"`, so it stays stuck in `inFromClient.readLine()`.

To make a quick fix I made this:

```
String valReadAux = "";
while(true){
    int val = sdf.read();
        if(val < 0){
            break;
        }
    valReadAux = valReadAux + ((char)val);
    if(valReadAux.contains("/EVENT>")){
        System.out.println(valReadAux);
    }
}
```

But is not the best solution, could you sugest me a better strategy? I also have a restriction of Java 6.

Comment: If you want to parse XML, then use an XML parsing library. Parsing in general is terribly bug-prone and is best relegated to mature libraries.

Comment: I Want to receive the xml, then i will parse!!